# How to convert from Object to Double[]

Tags: java, classcastexception

I have an object in Java 8 that is really an object array contaning Double objects. I need to check (using instanceof) and get the values. But I always get an error trying to convert to Object[] or Double[].

This is the variable in Eclipse expressions

[image]

I get this exception when running the code

```
Object position = whitelist.get("code").get("position");
if(position!=null){
     feature.setGeometry(new Point(((Double []) position)[0],((Double []) position)[1]));
}
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

But it works on ideone.com:

```html
<script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/J2ZJSV" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

**Edit**: [my own answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33541529/1654688)

Comment: Your object is an ArrayList, not an array.

Comment: ((ArrayList<Double>)position).toArray(new Double[position.size()]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whitelist.get("code").get("position")` apparently returns an `ArrayList` containing `Double` objects.

You can therefore simply write:

```
List<Double> position = (List<Double>)whitelist.get("code").get("position");
if (position!=null)
     feature.setGeometry(new Point(position.get(0),position.get(1)));
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved and writed the response while writting the question... but I consider your response correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned about this error. It's very simple error to solve, but now that I posted here (definitively this is not may best day) I will post also the solution.

The type of the Object is ArrayList, so I should cast to this type and check for this type.

```
Object position = whitelist.get("code").get("position");
if(position!=null && position instanceof List<?>){
    List<Double> point = (List) position;
    feature.setGeometry(new Point(point.get(0),point.get(1)));
}
```